# How to create a list from a specific key inside the nested object of JSON response?

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net

I've a JSON which I retrieved from `var responseMessage1 = await request1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();` and looks like this : -

```json
{
    "operations": [
        {
            "creationTime": "2022-06-02T10:28:28.765+03:00",
            "deviceId": "43432103",
            "deviceName": "P25-SC-0228",
            "status": "PENDING",
            "com_cumulocity_model": {
                "op": "s",
                "param": "waterStartDateTime",
                "value": "1/2/2018, 7:30:00 AM"
            },
            "description": "Generate Plan"
        },
        {
            "creationTime": "2022-06-02T10:28:36.276+03:00",
            "deviceId": "43432103",
            "deviceName": "P25-SC-0228",
            "status": "PENDING",
            "com_cumulocity_model": {
                "Mode": 0,
                "StopStationPayload": "[{\"ControllerAddress\":11,\"StationAddress\":26}]"
            },
            "description": "Stop Station"
        }
    ],
    "statistics": {
        "currentPage": 1,
        "pageSize": 5
    }
}
```

How do I create a list of values inside the key `description` such that I can store it in a list like : -

`var desc_list = ["Generate Plan","Stop Station"]`
and I can iterate through it like

```
foreach(var item in desc_list)
{
  //use item for xyz purpose
}
```

Which will output :

```
Generate Plan
Stop Station
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
var operations=JObject.Parse(json)["operations"];
string[] desc_list =operations.Select(o => (string) o["description"]).ToArray();

foreach(var item in desc_list) Console.WriteLine(item);

// Generate Plan
// Stop Station
```

Comment: this also works like a charm. I have a doubt about the key ```com_cumulocity_model```. Can I ask for a small help?

Comment: @saurabhdhyani Sure, what is your doubt?

Comment: If I take your solution, I'm using item inside my switch/case. So suppose if my ```case ("Stop Station")``` is satisfied how to fetch the value inside ```com_cumulocity_model``` which belongs to the same json object as the description? This should happen for any description which is satisfied inside the ```switch(item)```.

Comment: @saurabhdhyani You have to decide what data you need . if you need just description it will be one code, if you need all data if will be another code. Maybe you will have to post another question with what do you really need.

Comment: Yeah, I guess so.

Comment: @saurabhdhyani Let me know when you post your question. I have prepared the answer already.

Comment: Working on it. Have another query, so writing that in the question as well :D

Comment: I have posted the question. It looks like a mess though.

Answer (score 4):

Simple solution to do it convert JSON to C# objects and then iterate over Operation and read its Description property, as given below:

```
Root myDeserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse);
foreach(var item in myDeserializedObject.operations)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item.description);
}
```

Generate these C# object from JSON string from: https://json2csharp.com/

```
public class ComCumulocityModel
{
    public string op { get; set; }
    public string param { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public int? Mode { get; set; }
    public string StopStationPayload { get; set; }
}

public class Operation
{
    public DateTime creationTime { get; set; }
    public string deviceId { get; set; }
    public string deviceName { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public ComCumulocityModel com_cumulocity_model { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<Operation> operations { get; set; }
    public Statistics statistics { get; set; }
}

public class Statistics
{
    public int currentPage { get; set; }
    public int pageSize { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted as an end result. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

If it is just the description you need to output, if you need to store it, I would create a `List<>` (presumably it would just need to be a string) and for each item in the loop add `item.description`. Then you can use `list.ToString()` for output.

If you don't need to then you should be able to do `Console.WriteLine(item.description);`

EDIT: Never saw the other JSON object. You would maybe need to specify as `item.operations.description`

Comment: I want to create a list. And my question is how do I create a list from the given JSON response. I need to make use of the values in description in different places.

Comment: Apologies didn't realise you wanted to store the JSON response too. Seems like someone else answered it.